# An example where Lyapounov Condition is much easier than the Lindeberg?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

Currently studying the Lindeberg-Levy-Feller and Lyapounov's Central Limit Theorems, and was wondering - for sake of justification - are there any examples where verifying Lyapounov's condition is much 'easier' than verifying Lindeberg's condition?